# Same form for login and registration in FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, forms, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I am using the newest versions of FOSUserBundle and Symfony2. I have to provide a form that can be used for login and for registration. It has two fields:

- mail adress (required)
- password (only required for login)

and two buttons:

- login
- register

If the user enters his mail adress and clicks login, he will get an error that the password is missing. If he enters his mail adress and clicks register he gets an account and a password is generated. I already implemented the whole functionality, but I use two separated forms for login and register.

Now I want to merge these forms. This is what I tried so far:

```
    public function welcomeAction() 
    {
        $data = array();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add("email", "email")
            ->add("password", "password", array("required" => false))
            ->add("register", "submit")
            ->add("login", "submit")
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            if ($form->get("login")->isClicked()) {
                return $this->forward('FOSUserBundle:Security:check', 
                       array('_username'  => $form->getData()["email"],
                             '_password' => $form->getData()["password"]
                       )
                );
            } else if ($form->get("register")->isClicked()) {
            echo "REG"; #testing
            } else die("ERROR_WELCOME_FORM");
        }

        return $this->render('MyBundle:Index:welcome.html.twig', array("form" => $form->createView()));     
    }
```

I am using forward instead of redirect because it is not possible to pass POST parameters when redirecting.

When I submit the form by clicking the login button I get:

> You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your 
>   security firewall configuration.

So I changed the check_path parameter in security.yml from

> check_path: fos_user_security_check

to

> check_path: welcome (that is my route for Index:welcome() Action

and test it again. The error disappears as expected but I get two new problems.

First, I am not able to use the single login form with the new check_path anymore. This is because the original fos_user_security_check was removed, obviously. But I need to be able to use both the merged form and the single form.

Second, I get the error

> Invalid CSRF-Token.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Is this easily possible without hacking into FOSUserBundle or implementing the login action by hand? I need the same for the register part of the form but I think that this is analog.

Is this maybe the wrong approach? Can I somehow use the same field (email) for two separated forms?